# Solidity hardhat ^2.17.0 weird problems when compiling and deploying

Tags: node.js, npm, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "contract",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "hardhat": "^2.17.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

It's working fine in my current directory, when i tried creating another contract in another directory, upon using `npx hardhat compile` I run through this error:

**> Error HH801: Plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox requires the following dependencies to be installed: @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify, @types/chai, @typechain/ethers-v6, @typechain/hardhat, chai, ethers, hardhat-gas-reporter, solidity-coverage, ts-node, typechain, typescript.
Please run: npm install --save-dev "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers@^1.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@^2.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@^3.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify@^1.0.0" "@types/chai@^4.2.0" "@typechain/ethers-v6@^0.4.0" "@typechain/hardhat@^8.0.0" "chai@^4.2.0" "ethers@^6.4.0" "hardhat-gas-reporter@^1.0.8" "solidity-coverage@^0.8.1" "ts-node@>=8.0.0" "typechain@^8.2.0" "typescript@>=4.5.0"**

EVEN when i try installing all of these dependencies, `npx hardhat compile` works but i run into problems using 'npx hardhat run deploy/scripts ...`:
**TypeError: (0 , ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function at new HardhatEthersSigner**

Any explanation that satisfies my mental abilities?

Comment: Btw I just noticed that there may have been some updates when you npm i this package.json, as if i copy the node_modules from old directory to new directory it works fine, this isn't a solution but perhaps there have been some changes.

Comment: can you share your deploy script?